# springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository.save() not persisting data when called from CompletableFuture.runAsync

Tags: java, spring, database, mongodb, spring-data

Context: I want to save asynchronously data to MongoDb. When Front (eg. Angular/Mobile) call the Controller EndPoint it will call a Service method aimed to firstly save data to MongoDb and, if well-successed, post the same data a Kafka topic and call another endpoint passing forward the same data. In order to reach this behavior I want use CompletableFuture with "two steps": first save on MongoDb and after that (thenAcceptAsync) to post the data to Kafka Topic and thenAcceptAsync post to another rest service.

Issue: I am completely stuck to get the first "step" working: saving the data to MongoDb. I can runAssyncronously a simple system.out.print but never get ReactiveCrudRepository.save() persisting the data. See code below.

I am pretty the rest is working since if I try save without CompletableFuture everything goes fine with this method:

```
//properly working without CompletableFuture
public void SimpleSaveMehtod(Extrato e) {
    extratoRepository.save(e); // .subscribe();
}
```

Here is the service method code which "runPrintAsync.get();" works perfectly (prints the message) but "runSaveAsync.get();" didn't save at all. I gave a try by "ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)" and it didn't work also (honestly I don't think made sense await if I blocked with get btw I tried it).

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public void transferirVoidReturned(Extrato e) {

    ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    CompletableFuture<Void> runSaveAsync = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> extratoRepository.save(e),newFixedThreadPool);

    CompletableFuture<Void> runPrintAsync = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.print("I am printed"), newFixedThreadPool);

    try {
        // ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        runSaveAsync.get();
        runPrintAsync.get();

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In case it is relevant, here is the repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import com.noblockingcase.demo.model.Extrato;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

public interface ExtratoRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Extrato, String> {
    @Query("{ id: { $exists: true }}")
    Flux<Extrato> retrieveAllExtratosPaged(final Pageable page);
}
```

Comment: Are you subscribing to the publisher in `runAsync`?

Comment: No, I understand that if I subscribe I will block on that point. Am right? Well, I understand that save() returns a Mono<> and subscribe returns a Dispose. As far as I understand the only advantage to handle a dispose is if I want to cancel (eg. Let's say it take longer than I expected so I cancel the subscription). Since I don't want to cancel in any case I don't need a Dispose. Am I right? So I reached the conclusion that by only save and returning a Mono will trigger the save event in another thread and just before I return to original caller I get the result which will certainly block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: You need to subscribe to the `Mono`:

```
public void SimpleSaveMehtod(Extrato e) {
    extratoRepository.save(e).subscribe();
}
```

**Background**: one of many rationales behind using reactive types over `Future` and similar is that they allow performing computations lazily. This means, that when you create a `Mono`, `Flux` or any other structure and add some computation, it will not be executed until it's needed.

The way it is written now, as soon as the `Mono` is created, the thread is returned to the pool because there is no more work to be done. Since no subscription was made, the computation in `Mono` is never executed.

Comment: thanks. You answered my question. As a last comment if possible, do you think I am taking advantage by using CompletableFuture.runAsync while saving data with reactive driver (springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository)? I have in mind that is worth since I want to save to MongoDb and don't wait for returning hte confirmation from MongoDb. Thats is what I have in mind by "running Asincronously". I can later check if the data is there and don't wait for confirmation during save moment.

Comment: @JimC firstly creating a thread pool each time is not the best solution. If you don't want to block the current thread waiting for the computation to finish, I encourage you to use `subscribeOn`, where you need to provide a worker

Comment: am I creating a thread pool each time the code runs CompletableFuture.runAsync? I guess not. If so, I really understood something wrong. I understand it just picks up one thread from the already created thread pool. If you have any article or blog to read about subscribeOn/worker for saving data and not waiting for that I will be thanked

Comment: @JimC Take a look at javadoc, the threadpool is created at every method invokation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

Comment: @JimC I meant by running `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)`, you're creating the thread pool every time